# Why can't I get online? (the conference wifi question)

Tags: wireless

I am trying to troubleshoot hotel wfi that seems to work for everyone but me. Even my phone is connecting just fine. But not my Saucy Salamander laptop.

In `/var/log/syslog` I see a lot of "wlan0: send auth to ...1/3" (and 2/3 and 3/3) and"supplicant interface state:  disconnected -> scanning" (or authenticating --> disconnected).

Any tips on how to get better diagnostic information?

Comment: What wireless hardware do you have? Is it an open network or one that requires authentication?

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the contents of the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.  No internet then go to this link for running the script without internet.
<http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12350385>

Comment: @wild_man only my phone can get online so I couldn't run your script if I tried.

Comment: @lekensteyn  I have a Thinkpad X1. The network iya one of those open connections that steals your browser once you connect. I connected once, but can't anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment, but since I seem to be able to get online (Hotel Wifi is nothing if not fickle) I thought I'd try to spell out what's going on with Wild_Man's script:

`wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script`

So ... `-N` checks timestamps, `-t 5` only tries five times, `-T 10` timesout in 10 seconds. Presumably those options are to keep it from clobbering Dropbox.

What does the script do? It runs a whole mess of potential diagnostic tools:

`uname -a`, `lsb_release -idrc`, `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`, `lsusb`, `pccardctl info`, `iwconfig`, `rfkill list all`, `iw reg get`, `route -n`, `lsmod | egrep "(^|[[:punct:] ])${MODMATCHES}([[:punct:] ]|$)"`, `nm-tool`, `cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state`, `grep -v '^#' /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`, `grep -v '^#' /etc/NetworkManager/nm-system-settings.conf`